# How to grab the text from a kivy button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to build this simple GUI for a "voting app" where, by clicking the button with the candidate's ID, +1 will be added in the value of the ID key inside a dictionary. (counting votes on click basically)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

CANDIDATES = {"T1031" : 0,"T2112" : 0, "T4561" : 0}



class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    orientation = "Vertical"
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in CANDIDATES:
            canditate = Button(text=i, on_press=self.button_clicked)
            self.add_widget(canditate)

    def button_clicked(self, obj):
        print("button pressed", obj)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

So how can I grab the text displayed on the button ?
(Also, if any of you guys know...how do I put an ID on the buttons? I tried with writing "id = i" but the GUI doesn't even start when I do that)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the text value from a button using the `Button.text` property:

```
def button_clicked(self, obj):
    # Note that obj here is a button object
    # You can access it's text value, for example, using obj.text
    CANDIDATES[obj.text] += 1
    print(f"{obj.text}'s current vote count is now {CANDIDATES[obj.text]}")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to find the answer on google but what I found was too complicated for me as a beginner.